# Foreach on object returns booleans instead of values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to list all the object properties and its values using foreach.

It gives me boolean (0 or 1) and some strange things instead of actual property name and its value.

```
 @foreach($usersChangesLogRepository as $userChangeLog)
            Old:
            @foreach($userChangeLog->oldData as $oldProperty => $oldValue)

                {{{$oldProperty . ": " . $oldValue}}}

            @endforeach

    @endforeach
```

Output looks like this:
`Old: shouldSendToQueue: 1 incrementing: 1 timestamps: 1 exists: 1`

It should show user data like login, email, name instead.

What is interesting,  when I try for example this:`{{var_dump($userChangeLog->oldData->email)}}` the output is: `string(29) "myemail@gmail.com"`

However this: `{{var_dump($userChangeLog->oldData}}` gives me full var_dump of the object.

Why this foreach gives me booleans?

I am using Laravel 4.2 and PHP 7

Comment: Maybe try `@foreach($userChangeLog->oldData->toArray() ...`

Comment: @ljubadr Works! Thank you a lot. I probably should go home now, its my 15th hour at work haha. Best wishes!

Comment: Don't overdo it, take a rest :) `->toArray()` or `->getAttributes()` will return list of `attributes`.